# Не работает continue. Python

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        print('i =', i, 'j =', j)
        if i == 3 and j == 1:
            print('continues inner loop when i =', i, 'j =', j)
            continue
```

Comment: просто ничего не делает и не пропускает

Comment: должен переходить к новому i, но он продолжает j

Comment: Что вы хотите пропустить?

Comment: я хочу, чтобы когда i = 3 и j = 1, цикл пропускал i = 3, j = 2; i= 3, j = 3; а переходила к i =4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вместо `continue` вам нужно использовать `break`, вы же не хотите переходить к следующей итерации вложенного цикла, а хотите вообще из него выйти

Comment: хочу, в этом и проблема.

Comment: Вы хотите перейти к следующей итерации перебора `i`. Из перебора `j` вам нужно выйти совсем

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        if i == 3 and j <= 4:
            print('continues inner loop when i =', i, 'j =', j)
            continue
        print('i =', i, 'j =', j)
```

или

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        if i == 3 and j == 1:
            break
        print('i =', i, 'j =', j)
```

Вывод

```
i = 1 j = 1
i = 1 j = 2
i = 1 j = 3
i = 1 j = 4
i = 2 j = 1
i = 2 j = 2
i = 2 j = 3
i = 2 j = 4
continues inner loop when i = 3 j = 1
continues inner loop when i = 3 j = 2
continues inner loop when i = 3 j = 3
continues inner loop when i = 3 j = 4
i = 4 j = 1
i = 4 j = 2
i = 4 j = 3
i = 4 j = 4
```